# Softlayer API: How to get load balancer's bandwidth price for each datacenter?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, infrastructure

I'm using global load balancer, and i want to know the bandwidth price per each datacenters.

I have try the following code, but the fee in LOAD_BALANCER_BANDWIDTH is 0.
I'm not sure whether it is free or not. Supposedly i want to know how much cost per GB.

```
import SoftLayer
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(...)
items = client["SoftLayer_Product_Package"].getItems(id=805)
print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

The charge fee for bandwidth depends directly of the Load balancer´s associated device and not the load balancer itself (it means it will be charged for the device bandwidth´s capacity that was ordered previously on the server), see the following:

https://www.ibm.com/cloud/bandwidth

There is a server´s sample bandwidth pricing chart on url above, and if you see a device order for example in the same location as the chart (Dallas) you`ll notice the same bandwidth pricing packages as in the page above, see below:

[image: Monthly bandwidth pricing packages (Dallas)]

Currently the Load Balancer service is charged as per:

- its actual consumption
- total amount of data it has processed.

To find the charge fee for them and on which locations they are applied you can use the following code:

```
import SoftLayer
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(...)
objectMask= 'mask[attributes[attributeTypeKeyName], itemCategory[questions[fieldType, itemCategoryReferences]], prices[attributes[itemPriceAttributeType],categories[categoryCode],pricingLocationGroup[locations]],activeUsagePrices[pricingLocationGroup[locations]],locationConflicts]'
objectFilter = '{"items":{"prices":{"categories":{"categoryCode":{"operation":"in","options":[{"name":"data","value":["load_balancer_uptime","load_balancer_data_processed"]}]}}}}}'
items = client["SoftLayer_Product_Package"].getItems(id=805, filter=objectFilter, mask=objectMask)
print(items)
```

For more information see below:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/infrastructure/objectstorage-swift/object-storage-billing.html#public-inbound-bandwidth

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/infrastructure/loadbalancer-service/explore-load-balancers.html#explore-load-balancers